# JupyterLab: How to start a Notebook using Anaconda command prompt?

Tags: python

**The question:**

Starting a JupyterLab Notebook from the Anaconda Navigator is slow and even buggy at times. But starting JupyterLab from a windows or anaconda command prompt returns `Error: Invalid response: 403 Forbidden`. Does anyone know what's going on here and what I can do to successfully launch a Notebook in JupyterLab using a command prompt?

**The details:**

**1.** Launch Jupyterlab from Anaconda prompt:

[image]

**2.** Start a new notebook using `New > Notebook`

[image]

**3.** Error

[image]

The result is the same using a windows command prompt.

**Version info:**

```
Windows 7, 64 bit
Python 3.7.0
JupyterLab 0.34.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting the Anaconda Navigator as Run as administrator. Even in the terminal also, run the terminal with administrator privileges.